# Handling recursive models with springdoc

Tags: java, openapi, springdoc

So I have a nested model structure that looks something like this:

```
public class TagArea {
    private List<TagGroup> groups;
    
    ... constructors, getters, setters, etc.
}


public class TagGroup {
    private String tagName;
    private List<TagGroup> subgroups;
    
    ... constructors, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

And a controller that is returning said model. However, the schema portion of the swagger.json generated looks like this:

```
{ "components": 
  { "schemas": {
    "TaxonomyClientMetadata": {
      "type": "object", "properties": {
        "tagGroups": {"type": "array", "items": {"$ref": "#/components/schemas/TagGroup"}}
      }
    }, 
    "TagGroup": {
      "type": "object", "properties": {
        "tagName": {"type": "string"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An entire property just... gone. I would expect the `TagGroup` object to look more like this:

```
"TagGroup": {
  "type": "object", "properties": {
    "tagName": {"type": "string"},
    "subgroups": {"type": "array", "items": {"$ref": "#/components/schemas/TagGroup"}}
  }
}
```

Indeed, I'm currently migrating from Springfox pre-3.0 (so Swagger 2) to Springdoc with OAS3, and this is the behaviour I was previously observing with Springfox, and would like support for it once again.

It's possible this is related to the shift to OAS3, but I couldn't find any resources that suggest the spec no longer allows recursive types. I'm also currently not on the latest of version of springdoc (using 1.4.8) due to a dependency on a slightly older version of springboot.

Digging through the code a bit, it looks like the `ModelConverterContextImpl` keeps a cache of processedTypes (scoped to the current schema I think), and then adds them to a mapping cache when the type is finished being processed. In this scenario, we start processing the `List<TagGroup>` (and so add `List<TagGroup>` to the processedTypes cache), which requires recursively processing the schemas inside. When processing the TagGroup, we find another `List<TagGroup>`, we see that it's in the cache of processedTypes, then fetch it from the map cache. But because we never finished processing the original `List<TagGroup>`, it hasn't been added to the map cache. As such, null is returned, and the property gets ignored in `ModelResolver`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add `@JsonBackReference` jackson annotation, for circular references resolution:
springdoc-openapi is built on top of swagger-core, which is based on Jackson library for resolving models schema.

If you use the following definition, it will work as expected:

```java
@Data
public class TagGroup {
    private String tagGroupName;

    @JsonBackReference
    private List<TagGroup> subgroups;

}
```